# How to uninstall valley?

Tags: software-installation

So I installed this app with .run file. [valley](http://unigine.com/products/valley/) but now I do not want it any more so how do I get rid of it ?? there is a folder in home directory, should I just delete it ??
thank you in advanced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if all the files were installed to a directory inside your `$HOME`, then simply delete that directory.